# "Unarchive" a git repository

Tags: git

I have a git repo (local) and I need to un-git it so that each commit is stored in a folder and there is no sign of git. So it should result in folders of my branches and inside these folders folders representing each commit.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Well, something like this:

```
n=0
git rev-list --reverse HEAD | while read rev; do
  n=$(expr $n + 1)
  dir="$n-$rev"
  mkdir "$dir"
  git archive --format=tar "$rev" | ( cd $dir && tar xvf - )
done
```

This will put the revisions into folders numbered "1-hash", "2-hash" etc. (change the formula to calculate *dir* as appropriate).

Also this only works for "HEAD"... it's hard to come up with a numbering scheme if you need all the branches, and hard to know what to call the directories otherwise. Although you could simply use `git rev-list --branches` and then calculate dir as `$(git name-rev "$rev")`

Ideally you would be able to extract the files using hard links to represent identical content, but that would be quite a bit more work!

Comment: I was thinking you could simplify this a lot with `git filter-branch --tree-filter`.  It starts each filter in the root of a checkout of that revision.  You could make the filter `cp -a . somewhere-based-on-rev`

Comment: That's not really simpler, imho. Mind you, I wrote the above as a one-liner, then expanded it for clarity and added the revision numbering... not everyone is that comfortable with sh I guess. Also, using "git archive" and tar works from a bare repo, just set the GIT_DIR environment variable.